# How to solve for point perpenediculuar to intersection of two circles?

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

I am working through [Paul Bourke's formula to find the intersection of two circles](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/) and I am stuck on the step to find "a". I will outline the relevant part of the formula.

Consider two triangles: P<sub>0</sub>P<sub>2</sub>P<sub>3</sub> and P<sub>1</sub>P<sub>2</sub>P<sub>3</sub>.

let P<sub>0</sub> and P<sub>1</sub> be the centers of the two circles. 
let P<sub>3</sub> be the intersections of the two circles. 
let P<sub>2</sub> be the intersection between the two intersections of the circles and the line between the two circles.

let d be the distance between the two circle centers = ||P<sub>1</sub> - P<sub>0</sub>|| = distance formula on the circle centers. 
let a be the distance from P<sub>0</sub> to P<sub>2</sub> and let b be the distance from P<sub>1</sub> to P<sub>2</sub>.

Using the Pythagorean theorem we can deduce:

> a<sup>2</sup> + h<sup>2</sup> = r<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup> and b<sup>2</sup> + h<sup>2</sup> = r<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>

Here is where I get tripped up:

> Using d = a + b we can solve for a, 
>          a = (r<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup> - r<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + d<sup>2</sup> ) / (2 * d)

I do not understand where the formula to find a comes from. Can someone outline how this is deduced?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the equations `a² + h² = r0²`and `b² + h² = r1²`, you can subtract them to obtain

```
a² - b² = r0² - r1²
```

Since we know that `b = d - a`, we have:

```
a² - (d - a)² = r0² - r1²
a² - (d² - 2*a*d + a²) = r0² - r1²
-d² + 2a*d = r0² - r1²
2*a*d = r0² - r1² + d²
a = (r0² - r1² + d²)/(2*d)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I couldn't figure this out, It's so simple.